# Category setup and fetching CMS block from Custom Design template

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, custom

This Magento newbie is trying to create a new page layout and customization for level 3 categories.  What I've done at this point is use the Custom Design tab to change the Page Layout to 1 column and call a template with the Custom Layout Update:

```
<reference name="series">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/seriespage.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

In my page.xml files I have the block defined as "core/template".

But what I found is that in my template I could not access the category fields  with $this - calls to **$this->getName()** and **$this-getDescription()** returned null.  I finally was able to get them this way:

```
$category = Mage::getSingleton('category/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$desc = $category->getDescription();  // The right stuff
```

However, the category ID is still unknown and not returned from a **$category->getCategoryId()** call as I think it should be.  I see references to **$this->getCategoryId()** often.

Now I want to fetch the content of a CMS static block I've created, but this too seems to return null.  Nothing is output from a statement such as:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId->('my-block')->toHtml();
```

Using **$this** instead of **Mage::app()** didn't work either of course, and I tried other Mage variations.  I thought defining this template in Manage Categories would give it the proper context, but apparently not.  What am I missing to get **$this** to be set to my category context so the typical function calls work?

Answer (score 0):

please check that your template is loaded with some static content

if yes then you can try below code for that

```
$_current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
echo $_current_category->getName();
echo $_current_category->getDescription();
```

But in your case I am pretty sure that for `series`  `block type` is different please update your question with `your block type` for `series` if my solution wont work. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes, my series.phtml template file has lots of content.  I've been creating temp variables for the data for now and coding from that.  Your Mage::registry example works, just like my Mage::getSingleton did.  Is that a better method?   In page.xml I have the block type as "core/template", as I noted in my original question.

Comment: yes use my one, and mark my answet accepted if it help you

Comment: Sure I'll use the registry call instead of getSingleton but it still doesn't answer my question.   I want to be able to use $this in my template like other templates do, and I don't know why I cannot.   And I still cannot get my CMS static block.   Obviously I'm missing something...

Comment: please provide more detaail to your `block type` for that